# Concatenate many arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this code for concatenate two arrays.

```
import numpy as np
from hmmlearn import hmm
model = hmm.MultinomialHMM(n_components=3, n_iter=10,algorithm='map',tol=0.00001)
sequence3 = np.array([[2, 1, 0, 1]]).T
sequence4 = np.array([[2, 1, 0, 1, 1]]).T
sample = np.concatenate([sequence3, sequence4])
lengths = [len(sequence3), len(sequence4)]
model.fit(sample,lengths)
```

and it is working correctly. but now if I have more than two array. let us to say I have 10 arrays. how I can make the same process?

```
import numpy as np
from hmmlearn import hmm
model = hmm.MultinomialHMM(n_components=3, n_iter=10,algorithm='map',tol=0.00001)
sample = np.array([])
lengths = []
for i in range(1:10)
    ?????????????
model.fit(sample,lengths)
```

Comment: So, you'd probably need the new array `sample` and the lengths of them in list `lengths`?

Comment: You can concatenate many arrays at once.  Just put them all in the argument list. But the dimensions have to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to concatenate more than one array, you simply concatenate the array with the concatenation of all the previous arrays.

```
# Create arrays
arrays=[
    np.array([1,2,3]),
    np.array([4,5,6]),
    np.array([7,8,9])
]

# Create an array to return to
sample = np.array([])

for array in arrays:
    sample = np.concatenate([sample, array])

# Print results
print('sample', sample)
print('length', len(sample))
```

Comment: it still give me this error "ValueError: expected a sample from a Multinomial distribution." at this line model.fit(sample,lengths)

Comment: Just use `concatenate(arrays)`

Comment: now I have this error "ValueError: more than 1 samples in lengths array [3, 3, 3]" in this line model.fit(np.concatenate(arrays),lengths)

Comment: it is working with me now. The problem was arrays should be. 
arrays=[
    np.array([[1,2,3]]),
    np.array([[4,5,6]]),
    np.array([[7,8,9]])
]

Comment: and I used np.concatenate(arrays) direct without for

Answer (score 1):

You can use [vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)

That is,

> Equivalent to np.concatenate(tup, axis=0) if tup contains arrays that
>   are at least 2-dimensional.

store your arrays as a list,say `array_list`

```
print np.vstack(array_list)
```

Sample:

```
import numpy as np
sequence3 = np.array([[2, 1]]).T
sequence4 = np.array([[2, 5]]).T
sequence5 = np.array([[4, 5]]).T
sequence6 = np.array([[6, 7]]).T
array_list=[sequence3,sequence4,sequence5,sequence6]
sample = np.concatenate([sequence3, sequence4])
lengths = [len(sequence3), len(sequence4)]
print np.vstack(array_list)

[[2]
 [1]
 [2]
 [5]
 [4]
 [5]
 [6]
 [7]]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Since the arrays are already 2d, I'd suggest concatenate with axis=0.